# Use of transaction in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I create a stored procedure and I want to use transaction in this. So how can I use transaction in this stored procedure? Which part will start the transaction because `INSERT` and `UPDATE` both are together in this stored procedure.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertUpdateADAlertRecipient]
    @AD_User_ID int,
    @AD_Client_ID int,
    @AD_Org_ID int,
    @IsActive bit,
    @Created datetime,
    @Createdby int,
    @Updated datetime,
    @Updatedby int,
    @AD_Alertrecipient_ID int,
    @AD_AlertRule_ID int,
    @AD_Role_ID int,
    @Sendemail bit
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF EXISTS(SELECT [AD_Alertrecipient_ID] FROM [dbo].[AD_AlertRecipient] WHERE [AD_Alertrecipient_ID] = @AD_Alertrecipient_ID)
BEGIN 


UPDATE [dbo].[AD_AlertRecipient] SET
    [AD_User_ID] = @AD_User_ID,
    [AD_Client_ID] = @AD_Client_ID,
    [AD_Org_ID] = @AD_Org_ID,
    [IsActive] = @IsActive,
    [Created] = @Created,
    [Createdby] = @Createdby,
    [Updated] = @Updated,
    [Updatedby] = @Updatedby,
    [AD_AlertRule_ID] = @AD_AlertRule_ID,
    [AD_Role_ID] = @AD_Role_ID,
    [Sendemail] = @Sendemail
WHERE
    [AD_Alertrecipient_ID] = @AD_Alertrecipient_ID
    select @AD_Alertrecipient_ID
END 

ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AD_AlertRecipient] (
        [AD_User_ID],
        [AD_Client_ID],
        [AD_Org_ID],
        [IsActive],
        [Created],
        [Createdby],
        [Updated],
        [Updatedby],
        --[AD_Alertrecipient_ID],
        [AD_AlertRule_ID],
        [AD_Role_ID],
        [Sendemail]
    ) VALUES (
        @AD_User_ID,
        @AD_Client_ID,
        @AD_Org_ID,
        @IsActive,
        @Created,
        @Createdby,
        @Updated,
        @Updatedby,
        --@AD_Alertrecipient_ID,
        @AD_AlertRule_ID,
        @AD_Role_ID,
        @Sendemail
    )
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Thanks and waiting for your reply .

Comment: IMO there isn't a real need to use transactions here, since you are only dealing with one table. That said though, what's going wrong now?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the race between the `EXISTS` check and an attempted `INSERT` (where some other connection may also perform the `INSERT` between those two)? If so, I'd usually recommend just attempting the `INSERT` and detecting failure (if the row already exists, preferably checked by a `UNIQUE` constraint on the table) and then perform the `UPDATE` if it fails. Which is okay so long as you don't also have to cope with `DELETE`s from the table.

Comment: @shree.pat18 for safety of `INSERT` and `UPDATE` i want to use `TRANS`